# Symfony - Getter and Setter missing

Tags: symfony, object, doctrine, setter, getter

I have a basic controller where an object should be updated:

(I hardcoded the id for testing)

```
namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

class UserController extends Controller {

    /**
     * @Route("/lorem", name="ipsum")
     */
    public function defaultAction(Request $request) {

        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $user = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Customer\Customer')->find(3);

        if (!$user) {
            throw $this->createNotFoundException(
                'No user found for id 3'
            );
        }

        // I cant access setter and getter from user object !
        $user->setName('afsd');

        $em->flush();

        return $this->render(
            'AppBundle:directoy:index.html.twig',
            []
        );

    }

}
```

When i want to use setter and getter on the user object, i cant.

```
Method setName() not found...
```

Anybody could imagine why?

Thanks and Greetings!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you really have the function? i.e the setName() function.

take a look at this
http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/reverse_engineering.html

alos post the exact exception that you get please.